# ORA-00936: missing expression for dynamic data

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error, ora-00936

I have 2 queries, which takes data dynamically.

1. `Select cid from table1 where cNumber={{custNbr}}`

Here {{custNbr}} comes from a .txt file.

2. `update table2 set status='A' where customer_id=NVL({{cid}},0000)`

Here {{customer_id}} comes from output of step 1.

***Issue***: When step 1 returns NULL, it actually returns an empty string `''`. As a result, Step 2 translates to -

```
update table2 set status='A' where customer_id=NVL(,0000)
```

This throws an error java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression

How do I rewrite the queries to make them work.

Comment: Your queries are perfectly fine. The error is in the logic surrounding them - what exactly does it mean when you get a cid of NULL ? Is this an error in your data? Should the UPDATE simply be skipped in that case?
If you need further help, please [edit] your question and add the Java code you're using to make it a [MCVE] - your first query might not return any rows at all, and cid might simply be left uninitialized.

Comment: The select can return null values, in case there is no data for a given cNumber. In that case, update can be skipped or just run with no errors. I have no java code for this, as these are from steps while testing on DevTest tool. Step 1 and 2 are two consecutive steps in the testing tool.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it's probably sufficient to provide a fallback for the result of the first query:

```
Select nvl(cid, -1) as cid
  from table1 
  where cNumber={{custNbr}}
```

This assumes that -1 does not appear as a customer ID in table2. Therefore, the `UPDATE` will be syntactically valid, but it will update zero rows.

*CAVEAT*

However, I'd be strongly suspicious of a tool that cannot handle `NULL` values as input to Database queries. You might want to contact the DevTest support regarding this.